# Getting HTML Not Found when trying the Flask Tutorial in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, flask, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm just getting started with VSCode and working through the
[Flask Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask)

The 2nd example shows how to use app.route to go to a a default or a specific page:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"

@app.route("/hello/<name>")
def hello_there(name):
    ...
```

While the first route works, the 2nd does not.

The first route works - I see "Hello Flask!" in my browser when I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000

The 2nd route does not work - I try to go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/VSCode and I get:

> Not Found, The requested URL was not found on the server...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the `<name>` in your second route. It shold look like this:

```py
@app.route("/hello/<name>")  # not "/hello/"
def hello_there(name):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I definitely have the /<name> in there. I've tried it with and without and if I accidentally posted without it, my bad. But even with it in there, and I copied the code directly from the tutorial, I still get Not Found.

Comment: Try adding `app.run()` below your routes and running the script directly (`python app.py`) to see if there's a problem with your VSCode configuration or flask setup.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's the usual problem that I typically forget to check. I simply terminated VSCode and restarted it and now it works. So it must have been some part of the run/debug testing inside VSCode that needed a restart after adding this code. I'm not sure exactly what the sequence of things inside VSCode would be to do that, but simply restarting the entire thing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Its becuase you may not be running http://127.0.0.1:5000 currently. To run http://127.0.0.1:5000 you need to go to the terminal and find the directory of the folder that holds your flask file and type in:

```
python "flaskapp.py"
```

or what ever your filename is. Make sure it has quotation marks around it! However if you use python3 then it will be this:

```
python3 "flaskapp.py"
```

Then it will show something a new number that looks similer to the first. Paste it into your browser and click enter. And then it should show up.
If it doesn't then there's probobly just a bug in the code. If it still won't work you can build of of this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def home():
    return 'Hello!';

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```